# R dynamically naming a data frame to be used in ggplot2

Tags: r, dynamic, ggplot2

Yes, I know there are lots of questions about dynamically naming variables in R, and yes, I have reviewed them, and no, I still can't do what I want to do.

I have created five different data frames, each holding selected info from another data frame. I want to send each of these smaller data frames to ggplot. I've created the frames, but I can't seem to get ggplot to resolve the dynamic data frame name. I've tried various version of assign, and as.name.

Here's my truncated code:

```
Alist <- unique(bigdf$initial.A)
Blist <- unique(bigdf$initial.B)

for ( i in Alist ) { 
    for ( j in Blist ) {
        assign( paste0("a", i, "b", j ), bigdf %>%
        filter( initial.A == i, initial.B == j ))
    }
}
```

This works just fine, I have created the correct number of data frames, correctly named, and containing the correct info: a5b10, a5b20, a5b30, a10b10, a10b20 and a10b30.

```
for (i in Alist) { 
    for (j in Blist ) { 
        png(paste0("a", i, "b", j, ".png"))
        useframe <- as.name(paste0("a", i, "b", j))
        ggplot(useframe, aes(step)) + . . . 
    }
}
```

Errors are usually along the lines of: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class character ( or of class name ).

How do I create a dynamic name and assign it the contents of the matching data.frame?

And if you'd like me to use lists, I'll need to better understand how that would apply here.

Comment: So what would go into the list?

Comment: I'd love to use lists. And I see how I could loop over both the dataframe creation and ggploting together. But the loop does two or three things in each case, the i and j both name the dataframe and are used to select the information to go into the dataframes, and in the case of plots i and j are used need to name the png, call the relevant dataframe, and then (not shown) also create the title. I understand how a list could perhaps do one thing in each case, such as call the correct dataframe, but all of it?

Comment: @TheTime, you are absolutely correct in that I don't care about the dataframes, they are a means to an end and likely divided up because the whole algorithm became troublesome. Let me play with what you've offered and I'll post back. Is there a way to do the whole thing with lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get` should solve your problem:

```
for (i in Alist){ 
  for (j in Blist){ 
    png(paste0("a", i, "b", j, ".png"))
    useframe <- paste0("a", i, "b", j)
    ggplot(get(useframe), aes(x = step)) + geom_density()
  }
}
```

But you can easily do away with all that mess and use `doParallel` with a binary search on a `data.table`:

```
library(doParallel)
library(data.table)
bigDT <- setDT(bigdf)
setkeyv(bigDT, c("intial.A", "initial.B"))

foreach(i = seq(Alist)) %do% {
  foreach(j = seq(Blist)) %do% {
    x <- bigDT[J(c(Alist[i], Blist[i]))]
    png(paste0("a", i, "b", j, ".png"))
    ggplot(x, aes(step)) + . . .     
  }
}
```

Comment: I did not know get existed. I think it's just what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just keep the data all together and use a facet grid?

EDIT:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

plot_data = function(sub_df) {
  filename = 
    sub_df %>%
    use_series(gear) %>%
    first %>%
    sprintf("gear_%s.pdf", .)

  (ggplot(sub_df) +
    aes(x = wt, y = mpg) + 
    geom_point() ) %>%
    ggsave(filename, .)

  data_frame()
}

mtcars %>%
  group_by(gear) %>%
  do(plot_data(.) )
```

Comment: good question . . . I have four independent variables and want to use two to make a facet grid. So I need to separate out the other two.

Comment: I've added a way to do this with dplyr